# Can somebody explain this & target pointcut designators

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, aop

I am new to Spring AOP and was reading the docs for pointcut designators. Both this and target designators sound same to me. Can someone explain with a better/cleaner example? Thanks

**this** - *limits matching to join points (the execution of methods when using Spring AOP) where the bean reference (Spring AOP proxy) is an instance of the given type*

```
eg: this(com.xyz.service.AccountService)
```

any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) where the proxy implements the AccountService interface:

**target** - *limits matching to join points (the execution of methods when using Spring AOP) where the target object (application object being proxied) is an instance of the given type*

```
eg: target(com.xyz.service.AccountService)
```

any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) where the target object implements the AccountService interface

Link : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Answer (score 9):

The different proxying methods available, JDK and CGLIB, allow you to add more types to your object than those that it inherits. For example, you can declare a `Foo` bean that extends no classes (except `Object`) and implements no interfaces. For whatever reason, you can decide that you want to proxy this bean and make it implement the `Bar` interface and extend the `SomeRandomType` class. The target object here would be the bean of type `Foo`. The Spring proxy is an object that delegates to the target bean, shares its type, and additionally can have more types, as in the example above.

Therefore `target` refers to the proxied bean and `this` refers to the proxy.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! Guess I have to read more about spring proxies.

Comment: this referes to proxy and target referes to proxied Bean. Why a programmer would be interested in proxy. Proxy is used by Spring. what is use of this() in spring AOP?

Comment: @HakunaMatata If you want to take advantage of any behavior implemented through proxies, you need to access it through the proxy, not through the target object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : so this() is useful when i want to take advantage of Spring Proxy ?

Comment: @HakunaMatata See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).