# get handle of object intercepted by @Around annotation

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

getDescription method of Object of class Title was intercepted by an aspect. How do I get access to instance of object itself.

```
@Around("execution(String com.*.*.*.Title.getDescription(..))")
public String getInternationalizedTitleDescription(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    if (something){
        return joinPoint.proceed(); 
    } else {
        //here I need access to instance to Title
        //Title t = joinPoint.getObject();
        //return SomeOtherObject.getTitleData(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ProceedingJoinPoint#getTarget()` or `ProceedingJoinPoint#getThis()` depending on which object you want.

[`getTarget()`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getTarget%28%29)

> Returns the target object. This will always be the same object as that
>   matched by the target pointcut designator. Unless you specifically
>   need this reflective access, you should use the target pointcut
>   designator to get at this object for better static typing and
>   performance.

[`getThis()`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getThis%28%29)

> Returns the currently executing object. This will always be the same
>   object as that matched by the this pointcut designator. Unless you
>   specifically need this reflective access, you should use the this
>   pointcut designator to get at this object for better static typing and
>   performance.

Basically, `this` is the object that the method was invoked on (a proxy) and `target` is the proxied object.

Comment: what is the difference between two?

Comment: @riship89 See the javadoc (and quotes) and [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848738/can-somebody-explain-this-target-pointcut-designators/22849166#22849166).